# Angular: How can I intercept the call to a resource on the dev server and send something else back instead?

Tags: angular, rest, redirect, proxy

thank you for your help.
My problem is that in the production environment I have a file on the path

```
localhost:8080/content/language.json
```

with all my text that I need for the frontend. But in the development environment I miss some of the text in the file. It is present but useless for me.

I had the idea that I could intercepted the request to this resource and instead call an external api to get the complete file.

The following code was my attempt.
But it didn't work. It just returned the file that is on the filesystem.

```js
function setupProxy({ tls }) {
  const conf = [
    {
      context: ['/content/languages.json'],
      target: `http${tls ? 's' : ''}://localhost:8080`,
      secure: false,
      changeOrigin: tls,
      pathRewrite: { '^/content/languages.json': '/service_path'},
    },
  ];
  return conf;
}

module.exports = setupProxy;
```

Is it possible to interrupt the request to an resource and how can I do it?

Comment: try using HttpInterceptor. Check this link https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

Comment: Why can't you cache the external file locally for development? Is it that dynamic and you are depending on new values to be present all of the time?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.